# No event data after onEditComplete called in p-table from Primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the new p-table module from Primeng with editable cells.
When the editing is finished (return pressed) the `onEditComplete` event from p-table is fired and I am calling the method `goo($event)`. Sadly the event is empty/undefined/null. The primeng Docu says:

```
onEditComplete ->
event.column: Column object of the cell
event.data: Row data 
event.index: Row index  
Callback to invoke when cell edit is completed.
```

My table is visable and working perfectly.

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="header" [value]="data" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]" [(selection)]="selectedData"
  sortMode="multiple" (onEditComplete)="goo($event)">

goo(r){
    console.log(r); // null/emty/undefined
  }
```

I won't copy the whole table cause its to complex and too long.

I would like to get the currently edited row object/data. Why is the `event.data` not defined?

Comment: PrimeNG doc is out of date : Check [table.ts l. 2427](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts) and you'll see that `onEditComplete` only returns `field` and `data` properties. And I have same problems as you : I get `{field: undefined, data: ""}`

Comment: Cool. So thats a bug. Maybe it will be fixed soon cause Table is still a new Module.

Comment: Yes, you can create an issue on their repo if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the pEditaleColumn and/or the pEditableColumnField on the tag like this: `<td *ngFor="let col of columns" [pEditableColumn]="rowData[col.field]" [pEditableColumnField]="rowData[col.field]"></td>`

Comment: its working fine but when cursor move not next cell event not trigger any idea?